# react native, undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.thing = input')

Tags: react-native

I am trying to set the onSubmitEditing function of a TextInput object to a custom function, here is my code:

```
export default class Component4 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {thing: 'asdf'};
        this.func = this.func.bind(this);
    }

    func(input){
        this.setState({thing: input.target.value});
        // I will eventually do more complicated stuff
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{padding: 30}}>
                <TextInput placeholder="default" onSubmitEditing={this.func}/>
                <Text>{this.state.thing}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I would like the content of the TextInput to be passed to the function 'func' so that it can change the state of 'thing'. I realize I can just use an arrow function to achieve this and skip having function entirely however like it says in the comment in func I intend to add more complex behaviour there. Thanks for the help

Comment: <Text>{this.state.thing || 'abcd'}</Text> try adding || 'default' to the <Text> element incase the input is null maybe

Comment: it is probably expecting a string in the Text element but getting null sometimes so use an or statement to put a default in

Comment: See my latest edit. I think you were trying to update the state of thing to input. Since input is an object, and you're dropping this.state.thing as a child, you wind up dropping an object as a child, causing the error. input.target.value should be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind your methods to the constructor. You also need a method/function to handle text changes as well as one to handle collecting a result. edit: I guess now that I understand what you're going for, the button was unnecessary.

```
export default class Component4 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {myInput: '', myResult: ''};
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(input){
        this.setState({myInput: input.target.value});
        // I will eventually do more complicated stuff
    }

    onPress() {
        this.setState({myInput: '', myResult: this.state.myInput});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{padding: 30}}>
                <TextInput name='myInput' placeholder="default" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                <Text>{this.state.myResult}</Text>
                <Button onPress={this.onPress} title='Click me!' />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, see my edit to my question

Comment: I just noticed the OP was trying to alter state directly. Always use this.setState() after you originally declare your state in the constructor.

Comment: I fixed the type, still doesn't work, see my latest edit

Comment: This is encoraging, it doesn't give an error with that change however it instead sets it to the default 'abcd' (see the change that nathan suggested)

Comment: thanks but I want the function to be called when the user presses enter, with onChange the function is called everytime the content changes, what I want is for it to change to hte input, right now it changes to the default 'abcd'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173008/discussion-between-mccambridge-and-fred).

Comment: This looks really, good, thanks a lot, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

When you declare your function that way it doesn't have access to this because of scoping. Use es6 fat function to give it access to this. Also use setState function instead of direct assignment

```
func = (input) => {
  this.setState({thing: input});
  //more complicated stuff here
};
```

Also change TextInput to use onChange instead of onSubmitEdit

Comment: This is an ES6 class method declaration, not a function.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, see my edit to my question

Comment: @mccambridge that is a fat arrow function not a class declaration

Comment: @JasonMcFarlane The OP is defining a class in his code. You can't drop in a fat arrow function where a class method is expected.